# String substitution with VimScript dictionaries or Awk

Tags: dictionary, vim

I have a file with the following entries.

```
1 "A"
2 "B"
3 "C"
4 "D"
....snip....
1 2
2 4
3 4
.....snip...
```

Now I am wondering if it would be possible to use vim to substitute the pairs in the second part of the file with the original names for example

```
A B
B D
C D
```

The `1 "A"` can be thought of as dictionary entry, I need to know how to capture a large dictionary from the entries above and use it to do the substitution. I am not very proficient with VimScript but I came across an example of using dictionaries. Ideally I would want to have something like this from these entries

```
let mydict = { 'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3, 'D':4}
```

My vimscript is very scanty to allow me to define a proper function that transforms or provides the substitution. Any assistance is greately appreciated. 
The final document should look like

```
1 "A"
2 "B"
3 "C"
4 "D"
....snip....
A B
B D
C D
.....snip...
```

The entries are about 1500 and the reason am looking for a scripted solution.

Comment: vim can do it for sure, but I would pick awk for it. it would be an easy task for awk.

Comment: @Kent I would appreciate an awk solution as well!

Comment: okay, then I post an awk answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as OP commented, awk solution may help too:

```
kent$  cat f
1 "A"
2 "B"
3 "C"
4 "D"
1 2
2 4
3 4

kent$  awk '!($2~/^[0-9]+$/){a[$1]=$2;print;next}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=a[$i]}7' f
1 "A"
2 "B"
3 "C"
4 "D"
"A" "B"
"B" "D"
"C" "D"
```

If you love vim, you can execute the awk one-liner within vim. In the buffer:

```
:%!awk '\!($2~/^[0-9]+$/){a[$1]=$2;print;next}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=a[$i]}7'
```

As you see, the `!` was escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the dictionary `mydict`, it's simply:

```
:exe '[range]s/'.join(keys(mydict),'\|').'/\=mydict[submatch(0)]/g'
```

You'll have to define the range on which you wish to operate.

Note that if the key may contain `\` or `/` some little changes will be required. Worse, if the keys are not completely exclusive, you may have to order them, or to find a better pattern. If you know for instance that any number in a valid key, then the pattern would be `\<\d\+\>` and you won't need `:exe`.

You could even use this information to fill the dictionary. Something like:

```
:let mydict = {}
:g/^\d\+/let mydict[matchstr(getline('.'), '^\d\+')]=matchstr(getline('.'), '^\d\+\s\+\zs.\{-}\ze\s*')
```